# Unable to receive form data using post and action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, post

For some reason when I use the metod="post"  action="DisplayForm.aspx" and runat="server" I can't get the data to be displayed on a different page(DisplayForm) the .cs file string is being displayed but without the data from the form. I use regular HTML textboxes and did not finish all the cs file code because it all based on the same thing but the HTML is finished.
I don't want to use PHP or JS

form HTML

```
       <form autocomplete="on" runat="server" method="post" action="DisplayForm.aspx" id="log">

                        <h1>התחבר</h1>
                        <p>
                            <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u">שם משתמש: </label>
                            <input name="signinName" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername " pattern="{3,}" maxlength="10" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('שם משתמש צריך להיות בין 3-10 תווים') " id="signinU" />

                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">סיסמה : </label>
                            <input name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" pattern="{6,8}" maxlength="8" onivalied="this.setCustomValidity('סיסמה צריכה להיות בין 6-8 מספרים') " oninput="SetCustomValidity('')" id="signinP" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="keeplogin">
                            <label for="loginkeeping">השאר אותי מחובר</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" />

                        </p>
                        <% =st %>
                        <p class="login button">
                            <input type="submit" value="התחבר" />
                        </p>
                        <div class="change_link">
                            <p>
                                אין משתמש?
                                <a href="#toregister" class="to_register" id="join">הצטרף</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

DisplayForm.aspx.cs

```
    public partial class DisplayForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string st = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Signin vars
        string signUser = Request.Form["signinName"];

        //signup vars
        string loginUser = Request.Form["loginUsername"];

        st += "<p style='postition:absolute;top:20%;z-index:999;'>שלום" + signUser + "</p>";

    }
}
```

I don't have any code to send the data because as far as I know the method='post' does that. This code does work when I use it in the .cs file of the page where the form is placed so maybe I need to add sending code?.

In the DisplayForm page, there is nothing except the data from the form

Hope I was clear

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

**string signUser = Request.Form["signinName"];**

instead 
 
**string signUser = Request.Form["signinU"];**
The request.Form contains the name of the keys of the input rather the ID.

Comment: oops!! If you debugging DisplayForm onload, what does it shows the result for (Request.Form.AllKeys)?

Comment: Not sure if I did it right but the output is System.String[]

Comment: sounds interesting...To make sure we are on same page, you have two pages say (main.aspx,displayForm.aspx), The code you have attached is on the main page I presume. and you need to get the entered values from  main page to DisplayForm.aspx

I have worked with the same one you have attached like this and I am getting the result when I debug at DisplayForm.aspx

Comment: The attached .cs code is the DisplayForm.aspx.cs file I don't think so but may just worth to mention is the fact that I'm using master page(it's a different file not DisplayForm/main) affect it? But you are right we are on the same page

Comment: Master page is just a container and that is not the culprit. We just need to make sure the input field should have **name **. So when the page is posted we can get it using the name rather ID.

Comment: Its has a name for the c# and Id for the CSS and JS you said that using my code the textbox data does being transferred to DisplayForm right?

Comment: You used JS to transfer the data? Maybe I have bugged out files and the only way to fix it is to create new ones

Comment: just forget about the JS with your code it should work. Can you just use the developer tool or fiddler to check what all data its posting

Comment: Creating new files didn't work but I do have a qusetion does the input of the first textbox is being transferd for you? or just one word is being displayed in the second page?

Comment: just the text that we entered on the textbox

Comment: Ok that is strange tried to create new files but it does not work so I try to use fiddler to catch the HTTP traffic

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure how to read it first time using it but there is more than one local host things but they all say "Referer:http://localhost:51110/DisplayForm"

Comment: is there any possible way to share whole solution?

Comment: The whole project? or the fiddler?

Comment: Ok used different fiddler and seems that the data is being transferd

Comment: Fixed it! dont know how it just work now thank you for all the help